# Difference between Jquery $(window).load vs window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.743317, -0.331004),
    zoom: 12
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),  mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={APIKEY}&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

If I put

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    loadScript;
});
```

It won't load my map.  Error in google maps js is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Load'`. However if I use

```
window.onload = loadScript;
```

It will load it in fine.  I have absolutely no idea why.

```
$(window).load(loadScript());
```

Also works, just having it as a function that calls it doesn't. Could you tell me the reason of this behavior?

Comment: NB:
`$( window ).load(function() {
    loadScript();
});` doesn't work either

Comment: On Jsfiddle your code seems work in the same way: jQuery: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q5XET/) - window.onload [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AQgG9/)

Comment: On jsfiddle it won't work because my API key won't let it so I don't know how you can say they work the same way

$(window).load(loadScript());
Works, but putting it in a function doesn't.  I really don't understand this

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, what I wanted to say is that both code snippents on jsFiddle "do not work" in the same way... :-) However I confirm that the same code snippets, on my local pc, with my onw Google API key work without any problem (I have 2 maps of "Hull" in front of me in this moment...)

Comment: That's odd, maybe it's a rails jquery thing then rather than a normal jquery thing.  I'm interested as to why it's different more than anything.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually invoked `loadScript` in the `$(window).load()` version - you've just created a "void" expression that evaluates to a reference to that function.

Do either:

```
$(window).load(function() {
     loadScript();  // NB: parentheses
})
```

or:

```
$(window).load(loadScript);
```

That said, you perhaps want `$(document).ready()` rather than `$(window).load()`

Comment: @Baloo This is because your Jquery isn't loaded. Just try `alert(typeof $)` and you'll see that

Comment: I get the alert saying it's a function, I assume that means it's loaded.  Feel free to tell me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

in your jquery script you don't invoke the loadScript method...
Use:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    loadScript();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The $(window).load execute when all DOM is ready including images. That means if our web page has completely loaded including image then $(window).load function will call.

$(window).load(function() {

```
 // script
```

})

for more detail about $(document).ready vs $(window).load vs window.onload click on

http://www.delhincrjob.com/blog/what-is-document-ready-vs-window-load-vs-window-onload/