# is window.load() the same as .load() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a loading gif while everything loads on my site. I am using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
```

This works but

I am trying to get the same effect using jquerys .load(); Before I load the content within an element I will fadein the loading gif and fadeout after :

```
  $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.content').load('apps').css({"display":"block"});
  $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
```

but for some reason it seems that loading fadesout before the page is loaded. How can I get the same effect as window.load() so that the loading stays until the content is ready and displayed. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Jquery $(window).load vs window.onload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197636/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-window-load-vs-window-onload)

Comment: There is no `window.load()`...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback function of `.load()`:

```
$('.content').load('apps',function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
});
```